# How to share user data across multiple Wordpress websites?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, login

i have 3-4 sites which has content about traveling,and what i want is one site(main site content all the user data and) in all other sites, users can log in to the sites with that data ,how can i achieve that..,

Comment: if you can pls help..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods.

1. Run the blogs as a WP Multisite, since they would all share the same users, plugins, and available themes.
2. If you don't mind premium plugins, [WPMUdev has a user sync setup](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-user-synchronization/) that works pretty well. This is really your only recourse if you don't have a multisite option.